# JavaScript typewriter animation during generating random string from array;

Tags: javascript, html, animation, dom

I have a random quotes generator. I want to make when user click the generate button the typewriter effect happend. I tried a function from my previous code

```
//var txt = 'I don't want to make the static';
//                  var speed = 70;
var i = 0;

function typeWriter(txt, speed) {
    if (i < txt.length) {
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
        i++;
        setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
    }
}

function generateQuote() {
    document.getElementById("display").style.fontStyle = "normal";
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (quotes.length));


    typeWriter(quotes[random], 70);

    //  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML='<i>'+quotes[random]+'</i>';

}
```

The code gives me an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at typeWriter

What should i do to make the code work? Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is being thrown in `typeWriter` check that `txt` has been declared assigned a value else calling `.length` will result in this error.

Comment: Notice `...at typeWriter` part in this error message. Have things been the way you described, the error would have been thrown in `generateQuote` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `typeWriter` call delayed with `setTimeout` won't get any arguments passed - hence `txt` value will be `undefined`. One way around this problem is creating inner function inside `typeWriter`, then using it in `setTimeout`:

```
function typeWriter(txt, speed) {
    var i = 0;
    (function addLetter() {
       document.getElementById("display").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
       i++;
       if (i < txt.length) {
         setTimeout(addLetter, speed);
       }
    })();
}
```

Here `addLetter` has both `txt`, `speed` and `i` in its scope.